# Python dictionary update and refinement loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a loop that will further refine a user defined dictionary after original pass and parse of user string:

```
product_info = {'make': [], 'year': [], 'color': []}

make = ['honda','bmw','acura']
year = ['2013','2014','2015','2016']
colors = ['black','grey','red','blue']

user_input = raw_input()

for m in make:
    if m in user_input:
        product_info['make'].append(m)
for y in year:
    if y in user_input:
        product_info['year'].append(y)
for c in color:
    if c in user_input:
        product_info['color'].append(c)
```

Here is where I would like to check that dictionary and make sure that all values are filled, and if not, ask for more input to refine the existing dictionary:

example: `I am looking for a grey car`

```
product_info = {'make': [], 'year': [], 'color': ['grey']}

if product_info['make'] is null:
    print 'what make of car are you looking for?'

    new_input = 'i am looking for a 2015 honda'
```

send the string again through the dictionary/parse process and update the product_info dictionary if there is a value to fill in and also look to see if they mentioned a year this time around, etc…

updated dict:

```
product_info = {'make': ['honda'], 'year': ['2015'], 'color': ['grey']}
```

How do I take in new user input requesting more information and parse through it, looking for the attributes, and update the existing dictionary without modifying old attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while [] in product_info.values():
    for key in product_info:
        if product_info[key] == []:
            print("What",key)
            user_input = raw_input() 
            for each in user_input.split(' '):
                if each in make:
                    key = 'make'
                    product_info[key].append(each)
                elif each in year:
                    key = 'year'
                    product_info[key].append(each)
                elif each in colors:
                    key = 'color'
                    product_info[key].append(each)
```

This very rough, working system, you could refine it, but that's up to you.

Comment: I believe the OP may also want to make sure the user enters "valid" values.

When prompting, you may want to include the list of acceptable input values for the particular key: `print("What %s? %s" % (key, values[key]))`. Of course, this would mean creating a `values` map that maps the keys to the valid values rather than having independent lists (`make`, `year`, `colors`).

Secondly, don't assign the user input value unless it's a valid value. This means placing the last line from your example above within an `if` block: `if user_input in values[key]:`.

Comment: `# use what you had to parse their inputs here`

I was hoping he would put in his user input parsing here.... maybe that comment wasn't clear enough, I guess I will update it with his user process logic

Comment: So this is very close to what I am looking for, however, I would also like to pick up other values if the use entered it. For example, if the loop asked 'What make?', and user happened to enter in 'black honda', it would just go ahead and parse the color as well, and skip the prompt to ask for the color key

Comment: @chattrat maybe that ?